# does VNCviewer need VNCserver (service) running on my machine?

Tags: vncserver, tightvnc, vnc-viewer

do I have to have VNC service running on my machine in order to use only TightVNCViewer? I want to connect to remote CentOS but I have still lockout and authentication failure with possibility`to login only once per about 24 hours.

I type correct password and I get authentication failure all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a server running somewhere to connect to.  But you don't need a server on your machine to use the view.

Unless you really know what you are doing, you don't want to connect to a server running on your own machine.  Connecting can cause problems with updating the view if the view contains the viewer.  It can result in feedback loops where the view updates to show the old view causing a new view update to be required.  Some viewers make it difficult to view localhost.